# using array comparison in FILTER EXCEL function in Include field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

hi, thanks for reading this post in advance and helping.

Please check the above screenshot.

I have one table called metadata contains 3000+ rows of variables grouped in some classification.

I want to use Filter function to return all variables from Metadata (Name + Description) where the classification is matched against a list of classification strings (for example the one starting at K7) and return all variables matching those classification. The list at K7 is dynamic so I can't type individual string names because K7 list is the output of a different filter hence it's dynamic. Also this list is around 1 to 20 rows maximum. Meaning, I can't compare the classification of Metadata with the K7 classification list simply because the array size does not match (as suggested by different post where this could be possible if both arrays have equal size).

Could you please assist what to write in the Include field of Filter function to make it cross check the CLASSIFICATION of Metadata column 4 against the classification at K7? thank you.

thanks for the help in advance.

Regards
Samer.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a data sample and expect output.  Also show what you tried.

Comment: Please also read the comments at BigBen's answer there.

Comment: Further to my answer below, check out Mike Girvin's short video on YouTube demonstrating the `ISNUMBER() + XMATCH()` method: [Excel FILTER Function to Extract Records Based on Items in a List](https://youtu.be/aVgDoPKEJOc?si=8QGv4mstDm-dGQze)

Comment: Please post data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** do not post images, also what you have tried, the formulas posted on the other link, which you have removed in your present should have resolved your query, have you tried to follow them. this seems a duplicate query.

Comment: `=FILTER(MetaData[NAME],ISNUMBER(MATCH(MetaData[CLASSIFICATION],K7#,0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've stated the list to filter by in cell `K7` is dynamic, you can use either one of the following methods:

**OPTION 1:** `COUNTIF()`

```
=FILTER(MetaData[[NAME]:[DESCRIPTION]], COUNTIF(K7#, MetaData[CLASSIFICATION 1]), "")
```

**OPTION 2:** `ISNUMBER()` and `XMATCH()`

```
=FILTER(MetaData[[NAME]:[DESCRIPTION]], ISNUMBER(XMATCH(MetaData[CLASSIFICATION 1], K7#)), "")
```

**NOTE:**

The trick with either method is to reverse the parameters... use the entire "Classification 1" column as the *criteria* or *lookup_value* and use the dynamic list in cell `K7` as the *range* or *lookup_array*.